# How do I get my direct messages with TweetSharp?

Tags: c#, twitter, tweetsharp

How do I get my direct messages with TweetSharp?

I tried this:

```
var twitterApp = new TwitterService(OAuthConsumerKey, OAuthConsumerSecret);

twitterApp.AuthenticateWith(OAuthToken, OAuthTokeySecret);
TwitterUser user = twitterApp.VerifyCredentials(new VerifyCredentialsOptions());
IEnumerable<TwitterDirectMessage> message = twitterApp.ListDirectMessagesReceived(new ListDirectMessagesReceivedOptions();
```

and it give me null.

Comment: Nothing is just null, I'll try to put it in a try catch then I'll post here if I find something.

Comment: I sent a direct message and it works, the problem is ListDirectMessagesReceived is seems like it does not do anything .

Comment: After you call ListDirectMessagesReceived, what is the state of the Response property on twitterApp? What status code/reason phrase/content body is returned?

Answer (score 0):

firstly, you have to change permission, from "read and write" to "read, write and access direct messages"

secondly, you have to regenarate consumer key and secret, access token and token secret and change their values in your app

thirdly, I reccomend to use class **TwitterService**

```
TwitterService service = new TwitterService(customerKey,customerKeySecret, accessToken, accessTokenSecret); 

var directMessagesList = service.ListDirectMessagesReceived(new ListDirectMessagesReceivedOptions { Count = 200});
```